# mov instructions & registers - confusion !

Tags: assembly

I am reading "Computer Systems: A Programmer Perspective", chapter 3 explains `mov` instruction, and explanation give in a book confuses me.

give a function (page 142 1's edition)

```
int exchange( int *xp, int y)
{
    int x = *xp;
    *xp = y;
    return x;
}
```

Assembly code of function's body

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax  //Get xp  
movl 12(%ebp), %edx //Get y  
movl (%eax), %ecx   //Get x at *xp  
movl %edx, (%eax)   //Store y at *xp  
movl %ecx, %eax     //Set x as return value
```

What confuses me, is what is going to be stored, and where
Here is how I understand this:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax  //Get xp
```

CPU moves +8 bytes up the stack(from frame pointer `%ebp`), takes the value stored at that location, and stores this value at the register `%eax`(to emphasis - stores the value, not the address)

I am right ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, it sounds like you've got it right. IMHO, the AT&T `8(%ebp)` syntax is less intuitive than the Intel `[ebp+8]` which is more clear. The brackets show that you're using the value at the address in the register, and the number is the offset from that address you actually want.

Comment: So in other words, because `%ebp` stores pointer, we use parentheses around its name, to specify that we are getting the value stored +8bytes away from `%ebp`. In this case, `8(%ebp)` contains pointer `*xp`. Later on, in line `movl (%eax), %ecx` we are dereferencing `xp` same way as we did in the first line of assembly code

Comment: Now, everything is straighten out. Parenthesis was the source of confusion !  Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is using AT&T syntax, which is of the form:

```
instruction     source, dest
```

Intel assembly is [the opposite order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax).

You are also right about the `8(%ebp)` moving 8 bytes up from the frame pointer. The reason it moves 8 bytes, specifically, is because parameters are pushed onto the stack in reverse order ("right" to "left" when looking at a typical function call). Thus, `y` was pushed first, then `xp` and finally the return address of the caller function (which is why you move 8 bytes rather than 4).

Comment: I still don't get it though. If the stack looks like this: `(ret_addr) -> *xp -> y`, with the stack pointer pointing at top of stack (`ret_addr`), shouldn't you get *xp by doing `movl 4(%ebp), %eax`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what is a stack frame. Learn what exactly `push` and `pop` instructions do. 
Before that code there was an

```
   push y_val
   push xp_ptr
   call exchange
.cont    
...
.exchange
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
// .. rest of code
// stack frame: 
   old_ebp_val  ; [ebp] points here
   .cont        ; [ebp + 4]
   xp_ptr       ; [ebp + 8]
   y_val
```

Comment: My question is not about stack, even thought stack is involved. It is about values stored in register and memory

Comment: @user Try implementing RTTI in mind. Always keep track of the types of values.